# No rows returned from a non-empty table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I use the following snippet to query a local SQL Server CE database in a `.sdf` file

```
try
{
    using (SqlCeConnection sqlCe = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["logdbcs"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCeCommand sqlCeCommand = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT * FROM logs", sqlCe);
        sqlCe.Open();

        var reader = sqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader();
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.HasRows);

        sqlCe.Close();

        return "";
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    throw;
}
```

The database has 3 rows, but this query returns no rows at all. I do this from an ASP.NET application, while debugging from local machine.

Comment: debug it and see if sqlCe has a correct connection string of your target database

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that HasRows is reliable on the Ce driver. Did you try just reading the first row?

Comment: or try Debug.WriteLine((reader.Read())

Comment: @FerasSalim The connection string is right, since the number of columns indicated by `reader` is 5, which is exact

Comment: @FerasSalim `reader.Read()` returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely using DataDirectory in your connection string (which you hide from us), so look in the bin/debug folde for a copy of your database file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Datatable dt = new Datatable(); 

try
{
    using (SqlCeConnection sqlCeConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["logdbcs"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCeCommand sqlCeCommand = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT * FROM logs", sqlCeConn);
        sqlCeConn.Open();

        sqlCeDataAdapter losqlCeDataAdapter = new sqlCeDataAdapter(sqlCeCommand);
        losqlCeDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    throw;
}
```